# Magento Cloud CLI cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired

Tags: cli, magento2-cloud

I am working on macOS Big Sure 11.6 and since Friday(01.10.) I face an issue with my Magento Cloud CLI.
I was working without problems and out of a sudden, this error occurred.

[image]

Has anybody faced similar issues? The whole problem might be related to this: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/   but I do not what to do about it, my system should be up to date.

Thank you for every hint!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66276070/composer-curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-cert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This occurs when the SSL certificate is not properly configured. Try following these steps:

1. cacert.pem from the official cURL website
2. Put this cacert.pem file in the directory (SSL folder) where you have xampp.
3. search for curl.cainfo in php.ini
4. specify the path to the .pem file in the curl.cainfo section
5. restart localhost server

Answer (score 0):

You can run `magento-cloud` with `-vvv` and you will see all the paths where it looks for a valid certificate.

```
[debug] Checked CA file /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt does not exist or it is not a file.
[debug] Checked directory /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt does not exist or it is not a directory.
[debug] Checked CA file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt does not..
[debug] Checked directory /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt does not..
[debug] Checked CA file /etc/ssl/ca-bundle.pem does not..
[debug] Checked directory /etc/ssl/ca-bundle.pem does not..
[debug] Checked CA file /usr/local/share/certs/ca-root-nss.crt does not..
[debug] Checked directory /usr/local/share/certs/ca-root-nss.crt does not..
[debug] Checked CA file /usr/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt does not..
[debug] Checked directory /usr/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt does not..
[debug] Checked CA file /opt/local/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt does not..
[debug] Checked directory /opt/local/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt does not..
[debug] Checked CA file /usr/local/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt does not..
[debug] Checked directory /usr/local/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt does not..
[debug] Checked CA file /usr/share/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt does not..
[debug] Checked directory /usr/share/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt does not..
[debug] Checked CA file /private/etc/ssl/cert.pem: valid
```

Then you can download the latest certificates bundle extracted from Mozilla from here: https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html

Put the downloaded file in one of the paths you see listed above, for example:

`sudo cp ~/Downloads/cacert.pem /etc/ssl/ca-bundle.pem`